# Why can't i access 'this' through the function below?

Tags: javascript, function, this

```
var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];
var ps = document.querySelectorAll('p');
for(var i = 0; i < ps.length; i++){
    ps[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        var j = 0;
        return function(){
            this.style.color = colors[j];
            j++;
            if(j == 3)
                j = 0;
        }
    })
}
```

I want to add click event on all my paragraphs so that they react independently on the click by chnging it's color

Comment: Returning a function in an onclick event handler probably does nothing…‽

Comment: @deceze excellent use of an interrobang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every function have it's own context (`this`). When you create new function it have it's own context. You can use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) - it does not have separate context and preserves one from parent inside. Or you can use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to assign your new function some specific context. I'd strongly suggest you to use `bind` since arrow functions are hugely overused and it can be hard to understand what is happening.

EDIT: See more precise description of this in commend from @VLAZ - it's important

Comment: "*Every function have it's own context (`this`)*" that's not true - [the value for `this` is determined at call time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work), not at creation time. The same function can have different values for `this` depending on how it's executed. Aside from arrow functions.